# what does a question mark in a file path mean, like ?/filename

Tags: unix, filenames

What does it mean to have a question mark as part of your file path? Is this specific to any Operating system?
For example what does this "?/.random_file" or "?/example.properties" mean.

Comment: Does it just mean its a wildcard / single char or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what matching syntax your shell is using, but glob syntax (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is relatively standard.  In glob syntax, a question mark matches any one character.